# How can I hide a component in React depending on the screen size?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to hide a Carousel component when the screen is mobile only and display it in tablets or larger screens. What would be the best way? I'm using bootstrap.

Below is an edited version of my code for simplicity's sake. As you can see, this is my home page and  is at the top. I want this to be hidden in the mobile version. Thanks for your help!

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { HomeStyled } from './style';
import HomePageCarousel from '../Carousel';



const Home = () => {
    
    return (
    <>    
        **<HomePageCarousel/>**
        <HomeStyled>
            <Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col>   
                </Col> 
            </Row>
            <Row>
            </Row>
            </Container>
        </HomeStyled>
    </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Below is the CSS, where I am using styled-components..

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const HomeStyled = styled.section`

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 576px) {
    img,
    p   {
        display: none;
    }
}

.left-alignment {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 140px;
    }    

img {
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}

.right-alignment {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-alignment {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: 50px;
    //margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: you have access to use `window.innerWidth` and decide the value of it to be and render your component conditionally

Comment: Add a media query:

`media(max-width:320px) {.carouselComponentClass {display: none}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) I added a class to the carousel component before but already thought that wasn't going to work. Have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

Define `useWindowSize.js` custom hook to get the current window width/height

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Hook
const useWindowSize = () => {
    // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
    // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // only execute all the code below in client side
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            // Handler to call on window resize
            function handleResize() {
                // Set window width/height to state
                setWindowSize({
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight
                });
            }

            // Add event listener
            window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

            // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
            handleResize();

            // Remove event listener on cleanup
            return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        }
    }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
    return windowSize;
};

export default useWindowSize;
```

in your code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { HomeStyled } from './style';
import HomePageCarousel from '../Carousel';

import useWindowSize from '.path/to/your/hooks/useWindowSize'

const Home = () => {
    
    const size = useWindowSize();    

    return (
    <>    
        {size.width > 600 && <HomePageCarousel/>}
        <HomeStyled>
            <Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col>   
                </Col> 
            </Row>
            <Row>
            </Row>
            </Container>
        </HomeStyled>
    </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Using `window.innerWidth` inside returned markup is wrong, because its value may change independently of react render cycles. If you want to go this way, you need install window resize listener in a `useEffect` hook, which (the listener) should save width values into local state, which triggers re-renders, and that value from the state can be used in markup similar to your example.

Comment: @SergeyPogodin, I have used `window.innerWidth` in client rendered apps and works normally

Comment: @Immanuel Jaeggi, please check this way. This should also work

Comment: @Amila Senadheera I use your code example and it works for me. Thank you! But there is a problem, in that the sidebar does not save the state after it disappears or appears. For example: my sidebar has filters; if I select any option and resize the window (the sidebar disappears), then the next time the sidebar appears, the selected options are not saved. Is it possible to make it so that the entire state of the sidebar is saved?

Answer (score 8):

The most **efficient** way to doing this is using the matchMedia API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

In React it will look like this:

```
const useMatchMedia = (mediaQuery, initialValue) => {
  const [isMatching, setIsMatching] = useState(initialValue)
  useEffect(() => {
    const watcher = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery)
    setIsMatching(watcher.matches)
    const listener = (matches) => {
      setIsMatching(matches.matches)
    }
    if (watcher.addEventListener) {
      watcher.addEventListener('change', listener)
    } else {
      watcher.addListener(listener)
    }
    return () => {
      if (watcher.removeEventListener) {
        return watcher.removeEventListener('change', listener)
      } else {
        return watcher.removeListener(listener)
      }
    }
  }, [mediaQuery])

  return isMatching
}
```

and:

```
const isDesktopResolution = useMatchMedia('(min-width:992px)', true)

isDesktopResolution && (
  <YourComponents />
)
```

EDIT:

[CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-cache-5pd06?file=/src/App.js)

Your code will look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { HomeStyled } from './style';
import HomePageCarousel from '../Carousel';


const isDesktopResolution = useMatchMedia('(min-width:992px)', true)

const Home = () => {
    
    return (
    <>    
        {isDesktopResolution && (
          <HomePageCarousel/>
        )}
        <HomeStyled>
            <Container fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col>   
                </Col> 
            </Row>
            <Row>
            </Row>
            </Container>
        </HomeStyled>
    </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: ok never seen it like that, so how could I best implement your suggestion into my code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-cache-5pd06?file=/src/App.js

I think it should work

Answer (score 3):

Well there are many ways in which you can get the screen size and then based on that screen size you can conditionally render components

The easiest way you can get the screen width is :-

```
const Home = () => {

const isMobile = window.screen.width < 600

  return (
    <>
        { isMobile && < HomePageCarousel /> }

        ...rest of the code
    </>
  )

}
```

Remember when you will inspect this code in browser make sure to refresh after choosing mobile screen as this is not a state variable so it will not cause a re-render. But it will work fine when opened in a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

In your (s)css:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .element-to-hide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

More tricky one (detecting modern touch-like mobile devices):

```
@media only screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse){
  .element-to-hide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there any other way, by using grid itself can we do? like fxLayout in angular we can hide and show div base on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

let me share u another way to do this, this guy really helped me, for my use case this was the best solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Dm7jkJ75Zk&ab_channel=CodeWithAlex

in the first 2 minutes explains basically all you need; you just need to install a dependency to use this:

npm install --save react-media

also, docs are clear and usefull:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media

hope I helped someone!!